# Spark word2vec example explanation and how to get similarity between strings

Tags: java, apache-spark, word2vec, cosine-similarity

I followed the example in the Spark documentation page to use word2vec, [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-features.html#word2vec). It worked but I didn't quite understand what it is trying to compute.

Are the output vectors the output strings representation?

If yes, I tried to compute the cosine similarity between them but I got negative values because the vectors are not positive.

Can Spark word2vec create positive only vectors?

How to compute similarity between a list of strings using Spark word2vec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The output vector(by using transform on dataset) is a representation of the document(possibly sentence or sentences) which is supplied to the model .So; in essence this output is a combination of all the vector representation of each of the words in the given document(most likely a simple vector sum).
>
> You can use findSynonyms to get "num" number of words closest in similarity to the given word. findSynonyms is based on cosine similarity only.
>      Currently I am using it to generate feature Vectors which I am using as input to  another model.
>
> In order to compute similarity between two strings as some kind of a no. you would need to implement some variation of findSynonyms method.The current implementation generates a cosVec corresponding to input string and then tries to find the word Vecs which are closest to this vec .
>
> I am not sure about the part whether it can create only positive vectors and whether it is at all required/(makes sense) to generate only positive vectors.

Comment: The ```Word2VecModel``` ```transform()``` returns a vector representation of sentences averaging the words' vector representations. To compute similarity between sentences Does averaging cosine similarities makes sense? Or would finding another similarity measure using the dense vectors representation makes more sense?

Comment: The averaging is not of cosine similarities .Essentially it is : SentenceVector = Avg of vector representation of all the words that form that sentence.... representation of a word as a vector is something that the model learns.For similarity of sentences you would need to find cosine between the vectors output by the model.